# why the number of partitions in sortByKey() is not equal by default to one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I execute :

```
list.sortByKey.take(10).foreach(println)
```

the result is not correct. However when I modify it to :

`list.sortByKey(false,1).take(10).foreach(println)`

I have a correct result

Comment: It is not clear what does true result mean. sortByKey by default does ascending order sorting. When you make it false it will do descending order sorting. So there will be difference in results

Comment: i just to want to emphasize on the number of partitions, i can not write: 
 list.sortByKey(1).take(10).foreach(println)

Comment: i mean by true result : a correct result

Comment: i can not write = it doesn' t compile

Comment: sortByKey needs two arguments or none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
  xxx.sortByKey().foreach(println)
```

Foreach runs in parallel across the partitions beacuse of that you will not get ordering. The order may be mixed.

2)

Following code is work for only 1 partitions and start breaking on cluster or 
 more than 1 workers

```
 xxx.sortByKey(numPartitions=1).foreach(println)
```

3)

```
  xxx.sortByKey().collect
```

Collect gives array of the partitions concatenated in their sorted order.

Comment: Logically, sortByKey should return a sorted list; i mean collect the final result after the parallelising subtasks ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by named parameters explicit assignment

like

```
 list.rdd.sortByKey(numPartitions = 1).take(10).foreach(println)
```

This should work